# How to write php If statement for multiple conditions true (Condition#1=true, Condition#2=true, Condition#3=true)

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a form with FromDate , ToDate, VendorName and GoodsName, and I need to show the result once everything is true

Example: 
  FromDate="11/20/2019", ToDate="11/28/2019", VendorName="Abdullah" and GoodsName="Wheat",

here is my code

form.php

```
<form method="post" action="purchase_report.php"  id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="date">From Date <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="start_Date" id="startDate">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="endDate">End Date</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="end_Date" id="endDate">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="vendor-name">Vendor Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="vendor_name" id="vendor-name">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="snack-name">Goods Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="snack_name" id="snack-name">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
                          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset">Reset</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

purchase_report.php

```
$start_Date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['start_Date']);
$end_Date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['end_Date']);
$vendor_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vendor_name']);
$snack_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['snack_name']);

if ( ($vendor_name == $vendor_name) && 
     ($snack_name == $snack_name) &&  
     ($start_Date == $start_Date)) 
{
    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM t_purchase 
            WHERE from_vendor ='$vendor_name' 
            AND goods_name ='$snack_name' 
            AND date BETWEEN '$start_Date' AND '$end_Date'";
    $result = $con->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $data = '<tr><td>' .$row["id"]. '</td><td>' .$row["date"]. 
                    '</td><td>' .$row["goods_name"]. '</td><td>' 
                    .$row["from_vendor"]. '</td><td>' .$row["no_kgs"]. 
                    '</td><td>' .$row["rate_of"]. '</td><td>' 
                    .$row["bill_rate"]. '</td><td>' .$row["now_paid"]. 
                    '</td><td>' .$row["v_balance"]. '</td></tr>';
            echo $data;
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you think about it for a few seconds, that IF will ALWAYS be true

Comment: Also I am note sure what your question is here?

Comment: It might be useful to see your Form. Also would be useful to see where you get data from the `$_POST or `$_GET` array in the PHP code

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly; else part is also there, that works fine

Comment: WHERE do you set these variables?? `$vendor_name, $snack_name, $start_Date`

Comment: $_POST method


purchase_report.php
```
$start_Date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['start_Date']);
       $end_Date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['end_Date']);
       $vendor_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vendor_name']);
       $snack_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['snack_name']);
```

Comment: Then SHOW that in the question

Comment: @RiggsFolly question updated

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: @RiggsFolly, sure will use PDO, thanks for the advice... any suggesion on if statement?

Comment: Lookup `isset()` and use that. Testing if a==a is no use at all

Answer (score 0):

you need to Change the SQL query.
 try this Query

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM t_purchase 
            WHERE from_vendor ='".$vendor_name."' 
            AND goods_name ='".$snack_name."' 
            AND date BETWEEN '".$start_Date."' 
            AND '".$end_Date."'";
```

Comment: Thanks, The issue is on if condition, sql query works fine